# How to change entire column's values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change the entire column's values. The values are like this

```
332450 457047024001990
```

2 numbers with a white space in between. I only need the first number.
This column has more than 5000 rows so it's very hard to do it manually. How can I delete the second number or only see the first number.  I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can simply use `Find & Replace` method.

Use  `*` <kbd>space and asterisk</kbd> to replace all things after space. Keep ***replace with*** field blank. Then hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button.

[image]

- `VBA` custom procedure is another option. You can use below formula to adjacent column to extract first part of number (before space).

  `=--LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)`

Then copy full column and paste as values to original column.

> Another easier method is `Text to Column`. Use space as delimiter to separate numbers between space then delete 2nd column.

Comment: Thank you sir. But I'm getting this error. " Search Key Not Found".

Comment: Which method do you try?

Comment: The first method. I've exactly typed whitespace and asterisk and left the "Replace With" field blank as you've instructed.

Comment: I have tested it to my excel and it works just fine. See this post. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3342-excel-replace-all-after-before-character-space.html#:~:text=Please%20do%20as%20follows%3A,%3E%20Find%20%26%20Select%20%3E%20Replace.